# Video Assets to test transcode quality

Tags: video-quality, transcoding

I was wondering if anyone knows from where I could get a few (short) video  assets in high bitrate to check the quality output of a transcoder.

Some context: A few years ago I was working on a VOD project and the person who was configuring the transcoders had a set of 4 videos that really pushed the transcoder (e.g. very clear water ripples, a few bees on top of a yellow flower... and I cannot recall the other 2). I remember this person telling me that he had picked those videos as they pushed different aspects of transcoders, so I was wondering if there's something out there I could reuse.

### edit

I haven't found so far a good set of free videos to push the transcoder, but I have found the following sources.

- [4k media](https://4kmedia.org/): Has quite a few free high bitrate 4k (30-60 fps) videos.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few resources I'm aware of.

- The [Video Quality Experts Group](https://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/vqeg/downloads.aspx) has a variety of test material available.
- [Big Buck Bunny](https://peach.blender.org/), with a CC license, is often used as a test asset.
- [Tektronix](https://www.tek.com/picture-quality-analyzer) at least used sell some test assets to complement their monitoring tools.
- [SRI](https://www.sri.com/engage/products-solutions/sarnoff-video-test-tools) has several test patterns and compliance checking assets for sale.

Comment: Thanks Michael! ... I still have bad memories of BBB after watching the start sequence a few hundred times long time ago :D.